# Is OLAP the right approach

Tags: olap-cube

I have a requirement to develop a reporting solution for a system which has a large number of data items, with a significant number of these being free text fields. Almost any value in the tables are needed for access to a team of analysts who carry out reporting, analysis and data provision.

It has been suggested that an OLAP solution would be appropriate for the delivery of this, however the general need is to get records not aggregates and each cube would have a large number of dimensions (~150) and very few measures (number of records, length of time). I have been told that this approach will let us answer any questions we ask of it, however we do not have repeated business questions that much but need to list the raw records out.

Is OLAP really a logical way to go with this or will the cubes take too long to process and limit the level of access to the data that the user require?